# Symfony2: mime_content_type() not recognized

Tags: php, symfony

My controller looks like this:

```
public function download($filepath)
{
    // Generate response
    $response = new Response();

    // Set headers
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filepath));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filepath="' . basename($filepath) . '";');
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($filepath));

    // Send headers before outputting anything
    $response->sendHeaders();

    $response->setContent(readfile($filepath));
}
```

Passing a filepath to it results in the following error message:

```
Call to undefined function MyBundle\Controller\mime_content_type()
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [File Class](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html)

```
$oFile = new File($filepath);
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
$response->headers->set('Content-type', $oFile->getMimeType());
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filepath="' . $oFile->getBasename() . '";');
$response->headers->set('Content-length', $oFile->getSize());
```

I have not tested by running code. Hope this works fine. don't forget to add

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
```

statement at the top of your file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. I added the class via `use`, but when I want to create a file instance via `$oFile = new File($filepath)`, PHPStorm tells me the class is undefined. how can this be? what did I forget?

Comment: @Max Please match your statement with **use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;** I have updated the answer too.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. But I get the message that the file was not found. Here is how I retrieve the filepath that gets passed as an argument in the code above: `{% set filepath = asset('bundles/mybundle/files/example.pdf') %}  <a href="{{ url('_route_bundle_download', { 'filepath': filepath|url_encode }) }}">
                                <button>Download</button>
                                </a>` What is wrong?

Comment: @Max oh!! You are passing url. Do you have file system path for the file? If yes, then assign $filepath as system path. ( e.g C:/wamp/www/project/file.pdf )